# Is inline asm part of the ANSI C standard?

Tags: c++, c, inline-assembly

I always thought it was but many IDEs and syntax highlighting tools do not highlight ASM in C, but they always do with C++. Is inline assembly part of the C standard (ANSII or ISO) or not?

Comment: There is no such thing as ANSII. [ANSI](http://ansi.org/) is the American National Standards Institute, which issued the original C standard in 1989. All later versions of the standard (1990, 1999, 2011) have been issued by [ISO](http://www.iso.org/iso/home.html).

Comment: How could one possibly standardize ASM? C runs on all sorts of different processors, each with its own different assembly language.

Comment: @RaymondChen: By standardizing only the syntax of the wrapper around the actual assembly code (see my answer for more details).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not in the ISO C standard (n1570 draft of C2011) as such, but mentioned in annex J (common extensions):

> **J.5.10 The asm keyword**
>
> 1 The asm keyword may be used to insert assembly language directly into the translator output (6.8). The most common implementation is via a statement of the form:
>
> ```
> asm ( character-string-literal );
> ```

Annex J is informative, not normative, so an implementation need not provide inline assembly, and if it does it's not prescribed in which form. But it's a widespread extension, though not portable since compilers do indeed implement it differently.

In the C++ standard (n3376 draft of the C++11 standard), it is mentioned in the body of the standard

> **7.4 The asm declaration** [dcl.asm]
>
> 1 An asm declaration has the form
>
> *asm-definition:*
>
> ```
> asm ( string-literal ) ;
> ```
>
> The asm declaration is conditionally-supported; its meaning is implementation-defined. [ Note: Typically
> it is used to pass information through the implementation to an assembler. — end note ]

but also not mandatory, and with implementation-defined interpretation.

Comment: Oh, damned double-tagging. Didn't even notice it had a C++ tag too.

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to popular belief, `asm` *is* in the C++ standard proper, but support for it is conditional. §7.4/1:

> An asm declaration has the form
>
> *asm-definition*:
>
> ```
> asm ( string-literal ) ;
> ```
>
> The asm declaration is conditionally-supported; its meaning is implementation-
>       defined.

That said, the "conditionally supported" means you can't depend on a particular compiler supporting this at all. Microsoft (for one obvious example) uses an `_asm` keyword instead, but with a completely different syntax (the assembly language is enclosed in braces instead of a string literal).

Answer (score 2):

No - inline asm is a common extension, but non-standard (and quite often implemented differently by different vendors).