# Is an "asm Macro" part of standard C?

Tags: c, embedded

We develop code for embedded PowerPC architectures.

Our compiler supports something called asm Macros.

Here an excerpt from the handbook:

> **asm Macro Syntax**
>
> An asm macro definition looks much like a function definition, including a return type and parameter list, and function body.
>
> The syntax is:
>
> ```
> asm [volatile] [return-type] macro-name ( [ parameter-list ] )
>  {
>  % storage-mode-list (must start in column 1)
>  ! register-list     (“!” must be first non-whitespace)
>    asm-code      
>  } (must start in column 1
> ```

Is this standard C? My compiler does not list this as an extension in his handbook.

Clarification after first answer:

I'm aware the part withen `{ }` is not defined by standard C. I meant the function like construct after `asm` and before the closing `)`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870489/is-inline-asm-part-of-the-ansi-c-standard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not standard C. Anything architecture-specific, like assembly code, is going to be an implementation-specific extension just about by definition.

Comment: Oh, sorry maybe i should have worded it more accurately. I'm aware that the part within `{ assembler or similar }` is not defined by standard C. I meant the whole function-like construct.

Comment: No, nothing about that is standard either.

Answer (score 0):

The `asm` keyword is not standard in C, it is reserved in C++, but in both cases the the syntax is implementation specific as described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/asm):

> *asm-declaration* gives the ability to embed assembly language source code within a C++ program. This declaration is conditionally-supported and implementation defined, meaning that it may not be present and, even when provided by the implementation, it does not have a fixed meaning.

It's use to define a macro is new to me and interesting however.

Comment: The syntax is not implementation-defined in C++. The standard (C++03 7.4) specifies the actual syntax for inline asm to be `asm "NOP";` and nothing else. The implementation-defined part is only the actual assembly inside the quotation marks, in this case the NOP instruction.

Comment: @Lundin : Good point, though that defined syntax does not cover the syntax in the question nor the input/output/clobber specification syntax in GCC, and historically there has been little standardisation - expect compilers to vary is my advice.  VC++ uses a different syntax introduced by `__asm`, which is the more correct form for non-standard compiler extensions.